# neo4j ruby wrapper create or update

Tags: ruby, activerecord, neo4j, rails-activerecord

Is there an alternative in the neo4j ruby wrapper to do a `find` and then a `create` if the node doesn't exist, in the same way you can do a `create_or_update` in `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Model.find_or_create_by(property: value)`. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/neo4jrb/neo4j/master/Neo4j/ActiveNode/Persistence/ClassMethods:find_or_create_by